# Mockito mock of SecurityManager throwing an exception

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I'm trying to mock the `SecurityManager` class.  When I run the following code, Mockito throws an exception:

```
@After
public void tearDown()
{
    SecurityManager securityManagerMock = mock(SecurityManager.class);
    System.setSecurityManager(securityManagerMock);
}
```

The stack trace is the following lines repeated indefinitely:

```
at org.mockito.internal.creation.MethodInterceptorFilter.intercept(MethodInterceptorFilter.java:42)
at $java.lang.SecurityManager$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$3ceafc0f.checkMemberAccess(<generated>)
at java.lang.Class.checkMemberAccess(Class.java:2157)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:1879)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.cglib.CGLIBHacker.reflectOnCreateInfo(CGLIBHacker.java:44)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.cglib.CGLIBHacker.setMockitoNamingPolicy(CGLIBHacker.java:20)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.MethodInterceptorFilter.intercept(MethodInterceptorFilter.java:42)
at $java.lang.SecurityManager$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$3ceafc0f.checkMemberAccess(<generated>)
at java.lang.Class.checkMemberAccess(Class.java:2157)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:1879)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.cglib.CGLIBHacker.reflectOnCreateInfo(CGLIBHacker.java:44)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.cglib.CGLIBHacker.setMockitoNamingPolicy(CGLIBHacker.java:20)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.MethodInterceptorFilter.intercept(MethodInterceptorFilter.java:42)
at $java.lang.SecurityManager$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$3ceafc0f.checkMemberAccess(<generated>)
at java.lang.Class.checkMemberAccess(Class.java:2157)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:1879)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.cglib.CGLIBHacker.reflectOnCreateInfo(CGLIBHacker.java:44)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.cglib.CGLIBHacker.setMockitoNamingPolicy(CGLIBHacker.java:20)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: That line works fine for me, in Mockito 1.9.0.  Perhaps you could supply some more information - which version of Mockito are you using, and (more importantly) WHAT EXCEPTION are you getting?

Comment: Sorry, I looks like exception isn't coming from where I thought it was.  I'm updating my question now.

Comment: I think what's happening here is Mockito is using the `getDeclaredField` method in its mock method, and since there's a security manager the `checkMemberAccess` method is being called to see if the Mockito object can do this.  How can I fix this though?

Comment: Just curious: why are you setting the security manager to a mocked one in the tearDown?

Comment: I'm overriding `checkExit` to prevent the application from exiting when a `JFrame` is closed.  I'm trying to test a class which creates a `JFrame` and I needed to tear down the JFrame after each test so `Frame.getFrames()` only returned the one frame I was testing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PS! You could also mock static method call to getSecurityManager() method.

Mocking Static Method
See maunal at http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage

Add @PrepareForTest at class level.

```
@PrepareForTest(System.class); // System.class contains static methods
```

Call PowerMockito.mockStatic() to mock a static class (use PowerMockito.mockStaticPartial(class, method) to mock a specific method):

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(System.class);
```

Just use Mockito.when() to setup your expectation:

```
Mockito.when(System.getSecurityManager()).thenReturn(securityManagerMock);
```

Comment: This is much easier then what I was trying to do.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Lauri where does `securityManagerMock` come from, where do we initialize it?

Comment: @Lauri Could you please look in to the question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46445422/cannot-mock-security-manager-using-powermokito]

Answer (score 0):

When you change the SecurityManager, you should reset it to the original SecurityManager after the test.

You may use the [System Rules](http://stefanbirkner.github.com/system-rules/) library for your test. Setting and resetting the security manager are just two lines of code with this rule.

```
@Rule
public ProvideSecurityManager provideSecurityManager
  = new ProvideSecurityManager(yourSecurityManager);
```

Within your test yourSecurityManager is used and outside of the test the original security manager is used.