# How to provide LocaleInfo in Mockito test cases?

Tags: java, gwt, mockito

I have a method which uses the following lines of code:

```
/* 1 */ DateTimeFormat serverFormat = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
/* 2 */ DateTimeFormat displayFormat = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("MMM dd, yyyy");
/* 3 */ Date thisDate = serverFormat.parse(prices.getCheckInDate());
```

When I call this method from my test case(Mockito), a `NullPointerException` occurs at line# **1**.

I believe it is happening due to Locale. I don't know much about Locales. I am pasting the stack trace too.

What is the right way to test it? Can I somehow provide Locale info from my test case?

```
testSetupMyTable(MyViewTest)java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.gwt.i18n.client.LocaleInfo.ensureDateTimeFormatInfo(LocaleInfo.java:201)
    at com.google.gwt.i18n.client.LocaleInfo.getDateTimeFormatInfo(LocaleInfo.java:159)
    at com.google.gwt.i18n.client.DateTimeFormat.getDefaultDateTimeFormatInfo(DateTimeFormat.java:808)
    at com.google.gwt.i18n.client.DateTimeFormat.getFormat(DateTimeFormat.java:625)


    at MyView.setupMyView(MyView.java:109)
    at MyViewTest.testSetupMyTable(MyViewTest.java:49)
```

Comment: Are Your test depending on the date conversion to be exact? I assume, that you are not interested in testing DateTimeFormat correctness, so you could just mock *serverFormat* and *displayFormat* to return fixed date.

Comment: Have you tried with GWT 2.5? It might fix this, as it now has some support for using `GWT.create()` in a plain VM (i.e. not a `GWTTestCase`, not DevMode, not compiled to JS)

Comment: Can you post the code of your test case, so we can see why it goes wrong?

Comment: @Lauri my test does not require the date conversion to be exact. But I think we can't mock static methods in Mockito. Can you show me how, if possible ? Thanks

Comment: Sure you can, look at my answer in another thread: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9347748/1218956

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encapsulated the DateTime formatting logic in a Util class:

```
class Util {
  formatDate() {}
}
```

And now I am mocking the method of utility class.
I guess I don't have to be worried about the testing of DateTimeFormat API as it is already tested.

In this particular case My test does not require the date conversion to be exact so this solution works fine, but what if I want the date conversion to be exact?

Answer (score 1):

You should better use **GwtMockito**. Imagine that you want to test a composite that formats date:

```
public class MyComposite extends Composite {

    private static final DateTimeFormat FORMATTER = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("dd MMM yy");

    private Label labelName, labelDate;

    @Override
    public void updateHeaderData(String userName, Date dateToShow) {
        labelName.setText(messages.hiUser(userName));
        labelDate.setInnerText(FORMATTER.format(dateToShow));
    }
}
```

**And** the test avoiding exceptions with my pattern used:

```
@RunWith(GwtMockitoTestRunner.class)
public class CompositeToTest {

    MyComposite composite;
    @GwtMock
    LocaleInfoImpl infoImpl;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        com.google.gwt.i18n.client.DateTimeFormatInfo mockDateTimeFormatInfo =
            mock(com.google.gwt.i18n.client.DateTimeFormatInfo.class);
        when(infoImpl.getDateTimeFormatInfo()).thenReturn(mockDateTimeFormatInfo);
        String[] months =
            new String[] {"ene", "feb", "mar", "abr", "may", "jun", "jul", "ago", "sep", "oct", "nov", "dic"};
        when(mockDateTimeFormatInfo.monthsShort()).thenReturn(months);
    }

    @Test
    public void should_whenUpdateHeaderData() throws Exception {
        // Given
        composite = new MyComposite();

        // When
        composite.updateHeaderData("pepito", new Date());

        // Then
        verify(labelDate).setText(anyString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to mock static method, you may just mock DateTimeFormat.

```
DateTimeFormat serverFormat = mock(DateTimeFormat.class);
Date date = new Date();
when(serverFormat().parse(any())).thenReturn(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use GwtMockitoTestRunner to run your unit test. This should fix your problem.

```
@RunWith( GwtMockitoTestRunner.class )
public class TestClass
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Sireon. Your answer might be helpful for someone.