# Cannot mock Security manager using powermokito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, powermock

By looking at the answer written by `Lauri` in [Mockito mock of SecurityManager throwing an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347354/mockito-mock-of-securitymanager-throwing-an-exception) I wrote a unit test by mocking the Security manager. Below is the test case

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(System.class)
public class TestClass {
    @Test
    public void testcheckSecurity() {
        //mocking the System class
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(System.class);
        SecurityManager secMan = PowerMockito.mock(SecurityManager.class);
        PowerMockito.when(System.getSecurityManager()).thenReturn(secMan);
        List<String> allowedClasses = Arrays.asList("ClassA", "ClassB", "ClassC", "ClassD");
        BaseUtils.checkSecurity(allowedClasses);

    }
}
```

and this is testing the static method below

```
public class BaseUtils{    
public static void checkSecurity(List<String> allowedClasses) {
        SecurityManager secMan = System.getSecurityManager();
        if (secMan != null) {
            StackTraceElement[] trace = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
            String callingClass = trace[3].getClassName();
            if (!allowedClasses.contains(callingClass)) {
                secMan.checkPermission(new ManagementPermission("control"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I debug the test case the SecurityManager `secMan` is null in `checkSecurity(List<String> allowedClasses)` method.

What I am doing wrong? Please help me to fix this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your test passes with JUnit 4.12, PowerMock 1.7.0 and Mockito 2.7.19

Comment: @glitch it might be that your system is having a security manager. I running this in a system where a security manager is not set.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `BaseUtils.class` to `@PrepareForTest` not a `System.class`, like `@PrepareForTest(BaseUtils.class)`

More information you may find in [documentation](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mock-System) and explanation why it should be done in such way you may find [here](https://blog.jayway.com/2009/05/17/mocking-static-methods-in-java-system-classes/)

Comment: the methods in the `BaseUtils` are the ones which I am testing so why you are asking to mock the class which is been tested. If if it mocked we are testing a mocked object not the actual implementation

Comment: I’m not asking you to mock the class. `@PrepareForTest` annotation does not mean that a class mocked, it means that bytecode of the class is modified to enable some features. One of such feature is ability to call mocked system class. I provided links where you may find more detailed information.